# Symfony2 post submit event on a form input that is generated after a pre set data event

Tags: php, forms, symfony

My case is the following:
I have a multi step registration form. At the first step the user selects his role (Buyer, Supplier) and proceeds to the second step. If user has selected role Buyer then the input field isCompany is included in the form. When user selects isCompany = true then additional fields appear. I want to attach a post_submit event to the field "isCompany" but I don't know how to do this as this field is generated by a pre_set event and it is not included when form is rendered for the first time. 
My form type:

```
    $builder
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('telephone')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'first_name' => 'password',
            'second_name' => 'confirm',
            'type' => 'password',
        ));


    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $isCompany) {
        if ($isCompany == true) {
            $form->add('company', new CompanyType());
        }
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $user = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if ($user->getRole()->getRole() === 'ROLE_BUYER') {
                $form->add('isCompany', 'choice', array(
                    'choices'   => array('0' => 'Citizen', '1' => 'Company'),
                ));

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $user->getIsCompany());
            }
        }
    );

    $builder->get('isCompany')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $isCompany = $event->getForm()->getData();

            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback functions!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $isCompany);
        }
    );

    $builder
        ->add('nextStep', 'submit')
        ->add('previousStep', 'submit', array(
            'validation_groups' => false,
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the second event listener inside the first event listener: i.e:

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
    // put your POST_SUBMIT listener inside $otherListener, see below for more details
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier, $otherListener) {
        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if ($user->getRole()->getRole() === 'ROLE_BUYER') {
            $form->add( //note this part:
                $builder->create('isCompany', 'choice', array(
                    'choices'   => array('0' => 'Citizen', '1' => 'Company'),)
                )->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, $otherListener) // $otherListener is the listener you use in the post submit event (just like you've included in the question)
            );

            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $user->getIsCompany());
        }
    }
);
```